# How to check if a file is closed?

Tags: python, file-handling

Please help me with a code that checks if a file is opened and closes it. I tried the code below and it is not working. I just need python to check if the chat.xls file is opened and if true, python should close chat.xls Kindly help this is what I tried

```
closeXl = r"C:\Users\R\Downloads\Chat.xls"
if not closeXl.closed:
    closeXl.close()
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'closed'

Comment: Your AttributeError seems to say that you should execute .close() on the file handle instead oft the path string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AttributeError seems to say that you should execute .close() on the file handle instead oft the path string.

```py
closeXl = r"C:\Users\R\Downloads\Chat.xls"
file = open(closeX1)

if not file.closed:
    file.close()
```

In most cases it would be a better solution would be to use the with-statement. It closes the file automatically at the end of the block.

```py
closeXl = r"C:\Users\R\Downloads\Chat.xls"
with open(closeX1) as file:
   pass  # your code here
```

If you want to check if a file is opened read-write from another process and therefore locked, you should have a look at:
https://www.calazan.com/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-locked-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

You should open file before accessing `closed` attribute

```py
>>> f = open('1.txt')
>>> f
<open file '1.txt', mode 'r' at 0x10de8c6f0>
>>> f.closed
False
>>> f.close()
>>> f.closed
True
```

Answer (score 0):

`file_object.closed` only works for files that have been opened by the same Python process. At some point you should have done `f = open(r"C:\Users\R\Downloads\Chat.xls")` (if you haven't, `.closed` shouldn't work). Then later you can check `if not f.closed:`.